# ROS workspace and visualization

Tags: ros, visualization, ros-melodic, 3d-visualization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am a complete beginner to ROS and have  question concerning, the structure of the ROS working environment. I got the Schunk robot from the link below into catkin_ws/src.

https://github.com/ipa320/schunk_modular_robotics

However, I still am not understanding the different folders and files and how they interact together to form the robot. Also i would like to visualize the robot. How can I do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347498/ros-workspace-and-visualization/) by [lisa.gebert](https://answers.ros.org/users/52853/lisa.gebert/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-03-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can visualize the robot by using the [URDF](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/urdf_srdf/urdf_srdf_tutorial.html) provided in the `schunk_description` to make a `moveit_config` package of your robot, then running `roslaunch your_moveit_package demo.launch`. See the [MoveIt tutorials](http://docs.ros.org/melodic/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/quickstart_in_rviz/quickstart_in_rviz_tutorial.html) for details.

Most of the other folders in the repository you linked contain packages with C++ nodes which control the product they refer to. They also contain a `msg` folder with the message format they use. There are [tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/DefiningCustomMessages) for these concepts.

It is true that the documentation is not very rich, and not all packages follow strict standards. But the `description` package usually contains robot defintion files (URDF). The others you will have to read to understand how to use them.

---

Originally posted by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) with karma: 2180 on 2020-03-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lisa.gebert](https://answers.ros.org/users/52853/lisa.gebert/) on 2020-04-03**:
Thank you for the answer!

**Comment by [lisa.gebert](https://answers.ros.org/users/52853/lisa.gebert/) on 2020-04-03**:
I have just created another question. I would highly appreciate it if you could also take a look.

https://answers.ros.org/question/348317/missing-link-in-manipulator-urdf-xacro-and-visualizing-in-rviz/

Thank you!

**Comment by [fvd](https://answers.ros.org/users/8631/fvd/) on 2020-04-03**:
Please accept this answer so the question is taken out of the queue.